# parameters where one is enum and the other oner one is union of string that are valid keys of this enum

Tags: typescript

I'm writing rather a simple sorting function for backend api.
If there's no sorting it returns an empty string.
If there's sorting it returns a value taken from an enum based on column + some minor modifications.
However I have a trouble regarding types.
`sort` when not null has, a `sortBy` which is `T` passed to this function (union of strings), this works ok.
I do not know how do I pass Enum to the function where sort. sortBy is a valid key of that enum.

```
type SortState = null | {sortBy: string; sortAsc: boolean; }

const handleSort = <T, K extends T>(sort: SortState, sortEnum: K) => {
      if (!sort) {
        return '';
      }
      const name = sort.sortBy as T;
      const order = sort.sortAsc;
      const newQuery = `${order ? '-' : ''}${order ? sortEnum[name].replaceAll(',', ',-') : sortEnum[name]}`;

      return newQuery;
 };

enum SortEnum {
  bar = 'bar',
  foo = 'foo'
}

type TableHeaders = 'foo' | 'bar'

const sortQuery = handleSort<TableHeaders>({sortBy: 'bar', sortAsc: false}, SortEnum)
```

Comment: Is this a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  Neither my IDE nor I know what `SortState` is, and it would be very helpful to see some calls to `handleSort()` so we can test any possible solution.  It's also unconventional to use `K` as a generic type parameter if it's not the type of an object **k**ey, and `K extends T` would indicate that it isn't.

Comment: sure, editing right now

Comment: It's confusing that the keys and value of the enum are identical; in general they are not; could you change that so I understand whether you want to pass in the key or the value?

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8BREm) would meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz works perfectly, please post it as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your implementation and call, I'd be inclined to make `handleSort()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` corresponding to the `sortBy` property of the `sort` argument, which is also a key of the `sortEnum` argument.  Like this:

```
const handleSort = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    sort: null | { sortBy: K, sortAsc: boolean },
    sortEnum: Record<K, string>
) => {
    if (!sort) {
        return '';
    }
    const name = sort.sortBy;
    const order = sort.sortAsc;
    const newQuery = `${order ? '-' : ''}${
          order ? sortEnum[name].replaceAll(',', ',-') : sortEnum[name]
        }`;
    return newQuery;
};
```

The `sortEnum` parameter is of type `Record<K, string>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to mean "a type with a `string`-valued property at every key of type `K`".  The implementation type checks because the compiler understands that `name` is of type `K` (if `sort` is truthy) and therefore that `sortEnum[name]` is of type `string`.

Let's test the call side:

```
const sortQuery = handleSort(
    { sortBy: 'bar', sortAsc: false },
    SortEnum
); // okay

const sortQuery2 = handleSort(
    { sortBy: 'baz', sortAsc: false },
    SortEnum // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~ <-- Property 'baz' is missing in type 'typeof SortEnum'
);
```

Looks good.  The compiler is happy when `sortBy` matches a key in `SortEnum`, and unhappy when it doesn't.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQzAEwDYFMDKIBOsC8MAPANIzoAeU6KEMACjiAA7p4CeJ67AfABQBYAFAxRMCLigAuGGACuqVDAA+MAN7jJAIXYySAGk14AghGAyARiBAYkMAL77hYo1ACi8gLYyASulA4yKSG0DgAlmAA5jzCAJQw+DzqzmJhAGYwfACEEnjxaikuojjoUHI4YDAA5FUA3IUODaCQsGAInugJrgB0uVA69SJizdAwuMhsXX29kqbAgy4jregA7gCKcmzsXQAGACRq45MA-NUAtFUwMjX2B0c4MKd9HnKeANptHQC63SXMqAhgOhjIo+FV9ODqvoLvEZM8vB92ugvg0XPYdgsxCUyhVZKsNltBvZBsIaK8YNg8C9PMkhqILAgHoQqgycOCGmlrF0qpyQFVhPZhMIlq4CThtoRECgMJSoII6epXDprqzIX05jI0ghUBBOo4GrLqXFajAAPSmsYAawQ7CFQhFfTF7AATF0pWgsJJ5S4NH1ldUGQAvNWzMya7W6hxOBWGrxmi1sJg4LLCc2iAB+mazmeIZzODCYrA4AYQwZgYTongrEAikXLlSg7FY1UbrBAGVjr35QlidqAA)